# Java: Can LD_LIBRARY_PATH access the classpath?

Tags: java, maven

I have this [multi-module maven] project with a bunch of binary files in its `lib` folder

[image]

which I load through maven, by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<forkMode>true</forkMode>-->
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>${basedir}/lib/</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>
                    <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>${basedir}/lib/</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to get rid of these binary files (and not check them in the repo) by including them as java dependency. So I created a jar file containing these binary files and added as a dependency:

[image]

No I'm not sure how to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to these files. I tried a couple of variations, but for all of them the library complains for not finding these binary files.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<forkMode>true</forkMode>-->
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>lib/</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>
                    <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>lib/</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You commented out the forking directive.  Once your JVM is running, you can't reconfigure it retroactively.

The configuration of the load paths is not dynamic, so the JVM launched to run Maven doesn't get the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and other directives.  Without the forking directive, no new JVM will be launched, so those directive effectively don't do anything.

With forking turned on, the child-JVMs launched will be configured as you specified, so they will have the expected behavior.

Since you thought these items would be loaded, the rest of your question is based on a false premise.  You might be better off "fixing" the forking issue, retesting, and then re-describing the (likely) new issues under the new environment.